# How would I add a return statement for this, and how do I call the method?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public class InputFileData {
/**
 * @param inputFile a file giving the data for an electronic
 * equipment supplier’s product range
 * @return an array of product details
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Product [] readProductDataFile(File inputFile) throws IOException {
// CODE GOES HERE (input data from a text file and sort into arraylists)
}
```

`readProductDataFile` is used to read a text file, and store it in an array of type `Product[]`. The code provided cannot be changed, I need a way that works with this code. I've managed to make file reading and sorting into array lists work in a different class, but running it in this way is giving me a couple of problems:

1) I can't call the `readProductDataFile` method from the `Main` class, as if it can't find the method (it's definitely in the correct package).

2) I can't figure out how to format the return statement, I've tried lots of different things but I just can't see how to store it as array type `Product[]`.

I haven't provided a lot of specific code so far because I don't want the answer to be handed to me on a platter (this is part of an assignment so I don't want other people to straight up do it for me), but would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to solve this?

To give an idea of how I'm doing at the moment, the following test code worked for me:

`ElectronicsEquipmentDemo` class:

```
public class ElectronicsEquipmentDemo {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Name inputFile = new Name();
        inputFile.privateName();
    }
}
```

`Name` class:

```
public class Name {
    public String privateName() {
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("myOutput.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String str;

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                char firstLetter = str.charAt(0);

                if (firstLetter == 'P') {
                    String[] list = str.split("/");
                    Arrays.toString(list);
                    String fullName = list[1] + " " + list[2] + " " + list[3] + "\n";
                    System.out.println(fullName);
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which reads from a text file and, if the line begins with *P*, splits into arrays and prints out specified values (although my attempt to add a return statement made it only return the first line, so still struggling there).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
public class Name {
    public String[] privateName(){
        String[] list;
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("myOutput.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String str;

            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                char firstLetter = str.charAt(0);

                if (firstLetter == 'P'){

                    list = str.split("/");

                    //Arrays.toString(list);
                    String fullName = list[1] + " " + list[2] + " "+ list[3] + "\n";
                    System.out.println(fullName);

                }

            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("File not found");
        }
        return list;

    }
}
```

Edit: fixed scoping issue.

Comment: That won't work with a try and catch, I think because the variable only sticks in list. I tried adding a temporary variable but it didn't like that either (I might have done it incorrectly though).

Comment: Need to declare variable outside of the try catch. A try block has a sub scope of the parent block. I should have caught that. I have gone back and updated the answer.

Comment: It says the variable hasn't been initialized, but I wrote String[] list = null; which fixed it, thanks :)

I can't seem to access list in the main class though despite returning it, System.out.println(inputFile) prints out electronicsequipmentdemo.Name@1db9742

Answer (score -1):

Well, for the first problem, only thing I can notice is that your method is `static`, so be sure you're calling it correctly.
Also, consider if `static` is really what you want/need.

For the second problem, `return list.toArray(new String[list.size()])` should work.

Comment: It won't recognize list in the return statement outside of the try catch, and it wont recognize toArray or size inside the try catch.

Comment: Well, you can use a temporary variable, and declare it before "try". Then, inside "try", add to that temporary a value you want to return. Off course, you also need to import java.util.ArrayList in your class.

Comment: If I do that, String[] list = str.split("/"); is an error because list is already defined. This is the main reason I'm stuck, every fix I can think of seems to break something else.

Comment: I hope this will help. As long as you add throw in your catch, you can have return statement inside try. So, you set String[] list to null at the beginning of try, then inside the loop add a value, then return it.