# How do I return data in an array of type Product[] using this data?

Tags: java, file, arraylist

```
public class InputFileData {
/**
* @param inputFile a file giving the data for an electronic
* equipment supplier’s product range
* @return an array of product details
* @throws IOException
*/
public static Product [] readProductDataFile(File inputFile)
throws IOException{
// YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

This code is meant to read a text file and store the data in an array of type Product[]. I know how to read in a text file and have it sort it into an array, but I've never seen code laid out in this fashion before (specifically "public static Product[]", and I'm unsure how to work with "(File inputfile)". I've looked all over the place but can't find any examples of anything like this. Could someone explain this to me?

EDIT

```
package electronicsequipmentdemo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author George
 */
public class InputFileData {
/**
* @param inputFile a file giving the data for an electronic
* equipment supplier’s product range
* @return an array of product details
* @throws IOException
*/
public static Product [] readProductDataFile(File inputFile)
throws IOException{

Product[] productName;   

try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("productDataFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str;


        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {           

           Product[] list = str.split("/");


           Arrays.toString(list);
           productName = list[1];
           return productName;



        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("File not found");
    } 
return  null;
}
```

This gives the following errors:
Product[] list = str.split("/");   incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to product[]

productName = list[1];             incompatible types: Product cannot be converted to Product[]

I've tried lots of things, but without knowing how this sort of class is meant to work (I've never seen a method written out like this), combined with the fact I've been trying to make it work for a solid two days, I've probably got everything wrong. I'm desperate to learn how to do this, help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you learned about methods?

Comment: Isn't this the same question: [How would I add a return statement for this, and how do I call the method?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29089478)

Comment: Yes, but I haven't seen one that works in this way before. It also won't let me call this method like all the others.

My main problem here is that I can't figure out how to use the Product[] and File inputFile parts of this.

Comment: Have you learned about parameters?

Comment: Yes, but I'm still unsure of Product[] and File inputFile and what they do. I'm very new to Java and haven't come across a method structured in this way before.

Comment: Please post the code of `readProductDataFile()` you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

This is a static method. See this turorial (or a lot of others): http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program

> Java static method
>
> Java static method program: static methods in Java can be called
>   without creating an object of class. Have you noticed why we write
>   static keyword when defining main it's because program execution
>   begins from main and no object has been created yet. Consider the
>   example below to improve your understanding of static methods.

Comment: I know about static, what I don't get is Product[] being in there, or how to use File filedata. I can do the process through other methods but having to use this format I don't recognize means I don't know how to structure the code or output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code
    package electronicsequipmentdemo;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author George
 */
public class InputFileData {
/**
* @param inputFile a file giving the data for an electronic
* equipment supplier’s product range
* @return an array of product details
* @throws IOException
*/
public static Product [] readProductDataFile(File inputFile)
throws IOException{

Product[] productList=new Product[100];  
int i=0;

try {
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("productDataFile.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

       String str;
       String[] list= new String[100];
       while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {           
       list = str.split("/");
       for(String name:list){
               Product product=new Product();
               product.setProductName(name);
               if(i<100){
                   productList[i]=product;
                   i++;
               }
          }

       }
        br.close();
        return productList;
       }

  } catch (IOException e) {

     out.println("File not found");
 } 
return  null;
}
```

The idea is that the read line method will return you a string, when you split this string using your delimiter you get an array of strings now you have to create a Product object using the setter method of the Product class(which you know i guess) the you need to add the product objet to the ProductList array here i have assumed that there are not more than 100 product objects and 100 names in a line of the file you are trying to read.

Comment: I can't set it to actually return anything; if I make it return list, it says it can't find the variable (because it's defined in a try catch). I define it before the try catch, and the try catch fails as it's already defined and won't override it.

So if I don't define it from the start, return list gives the error "cannot find symbol", and if I do define it the try catch gives the error "variable list is already defined". I can't see how to write it in order for it to treat it as temporary.

Comment: I also tried giving a return within the try, but it either says String[] cannot be converted to Product[] (in response to return list;), or .class expected (in response to return Product[] list;). I really don't know what to return for this.

Comment: I've also tried setting the variable up before the try with Product[] list; but it still tells me in the try that it can't do
    Product[] list = str.split("/");
because it's already defined.

Comment: Can you share the Product class...and some content of the file you are trying to read

Comment: I'm also not entirely sure of the format of what the Product class is meant to be, I know it's get set methods but I need to do this one first before I can do that. The content of the file isn't the problem, I've managed to make it work in a method of my own design, but I have to use the one I was given. The problem I'm having is one of how to structure everything.

Comment: I'm not quite seeing how to add the setter methods, I've been staring at this program for so long that I'm struggling to make sense of anything >.<

I need to be able to get the Product class to access the arraylist created in InputFileData, while also allowing the main class to access the data in the Product class. I made some get/ sets that allowed me to get the data from Product to main, but I can't get the data from InputFileData to Product.